# Recommended vim keymap "namespaces" for custom keymaps?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

Vim seems to have bound every key on the keyboard with actions. If I wanted to create some custom keymaps for often-executed commands, are there any keys that are recommended that I use or that are intended to be overridden?

Comment: Have you tried using the `leader` key?  It is `\` by default.

Comment: It is the ``\`` key by default

Comment: Forgot to escape the backslash.  :P

Answer (score 1):

You're right, for often-invoked mappings, the default `<Leader>` of <kbd>\</kbd> isn't optimal. Some people reassign via `mapleader`, but if you use many plugins, that again leads to contention and long `<Leader>abc...` mappings.

My approach is to keep the leader, and start the few quick and often-used mappings with `,` instead. The original functionality of `,` isn't that important, but I've reassigned it to `'` (for which I can alternatively use `` ` ``; I don't usually need line-only jumps):

```
:noremap ' ,
```

In addition, you have the *function keys* for very quick access (though you have to lift the hand from the home row). If you're mainly in GVIM, you can also map all Shift / Ctrl / Alt combinations; in the terminal, these might not work.

Finally, there are some unused combinations. For example, `yr` (though there's `y`ank and `r`eplace, there's no `r` motion), or `q` followed by any non-(writable-) register: `q.`, `q#`, ...

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you don't want to use a `<leader>` mapping.

There are an infinite number of possible mappings, you can check if one you are thinking of is in use by a plugin via:`:map`, `:nmap` and `:imap`.

You can check default mappings using `:help`

You may also be interested in Tim Pope's thought on the subject:

> [leader maps are pretty lame](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim/issues/14)